# Django / HTML - are forms the only way to send POST requests?

Tags: html, django, post, get, request

I'm reading a Django tutorial and in the tutorial, the urls.py is this:

```
(r'^vote/$', bookmark_vote_page),
```

and there is a model called 'SharedBookmark':

```
class SharedBookmark(models.Model):
    bookmark = models.ForeignKey(Bookmark, unique=True)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    users_voted = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

but in the template, the link which leads to /vote/ is this:

```
{% if shared_bookmarks %}
     <ul class="bookmarks">
     {% for shared_bookmark in shared_bookmarks %}
         <li>
             <a href="/vote/?id={{ shared_bookmark.id }}" class="vote">[+]</a>
```

The view which handles the link is this:

```
@login_required
def bookmark_vote_page(request):
     if request.GET.has_key('id'): #if it is a GET request
         try:
             id = request.GET['id']
             shared_bookmark = SharedBookmark.objects.get(id=id) #if the bookmark is found
             shared_bookmark.votes += 1 #make a change to the 'votes' field in the DB
             shared_bookmark.users_voted.add(request.user) #make a change in the 'users_voted' field in the DB
             shared_bookmark.save()
```

As you can see, the template appends '?id=x' (where x is a number) to the end of the URL and the view uses the GET request and makes a change to the database. From what I read, I should ONLY use POST requests if I want to modify the database. Is there a way for me to send a POST request rather than a GET request Without creating an entire HTML form / submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you should use a post request if you want to change data on the server.

If you're just using html, then you need to create a form and a submit button. If you are using javascript, you could add a click handler to the link, which submits the form.
Ui